# Suddenly, DotNetOpenAuth returning (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, authentication, facebook, dotnetopenauth

My application has been deployed for nearly 6 months and the latest release was about 3 weeks ago.

Suddenly, today Facebook Auth stopped working.  The webapp was not changed or redeployed and the facebook app settings were not changed.

Authentication with Twitter still works correct.

This is the exception:

```
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, DirectWebRequestOptions options)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, DirectWebRequestOptions options)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.GetDirectResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.RequestCore(IDirectedProtocolMessage request)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Request(IDirectedProtocolMessage requestMessage)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ClientBase.UpdateAuthorizationWithResponse(IAuthorizationState authorizationState, EndUserAuthorizationSuccessAuthCodeResponse authorizationSuccess)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.WebServerClient.ProcessUserAuthorization(HttpRequestInfo request)
```

Any idea what could have happened?  I see nothing on Facebook's site about breaking changes or  service degradation at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working again, leading me to believe that it was a bug on Facebook's end.

Answer (score 1):

Quite likely Facebook *finally* upgraded their OAuth 2.0 support to comply with a more recent draft of the OAuth 2.0 spec that is incompatible with the version of DotNetOpenAuth that you're using.   Try downloading the latest DotNetOpenAuth CTP and see if it helps.

That said, there's never been any guarantee of interoperability with the likes of Facebook or any other OAuth 2.0 server.  OAuth 2.0 is *not a finalized spec* and as such interoperability problems are almost a guarantee.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the response.  Strange thing is that suddenly started working again which leads me to believe that there was something wrong with Facebook for a few hours, and not an incompatibility in the library.